# Recommendations on a single dedicated app GUI for Debian

Tags: debian, gnome, kde, xfce, gui

I have a project that requires a Debian device to run **one simple custom app** on a touchscreen from boot to death. It shouldn't be possible to exit the app.

I've looked into Gnome, KDE, XFCE, and Tcl/Tk, but it's hard to tell which are the best for a single app rather than an entire desktop. What are the best options out there?

Bonus points if the solution is in any way easy to program and/or better than average on security.

Comment: Doesn't matter which you pick, as long as it can run in fullscreen without expecting a WM to exist.

Comment: @muru I think you're right. Thanks very much.